# Regex to match /src/main/{any_package}/*.java

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, checkstyle

I need a Regex for a set including only files from `/src/main/java/{any_package}/*.java` to apply CheckStyle rules only to these files in Eclipse.

All other files, e.g.: none *.java files, src/test/ should be ignored.

Comment: Why regex, when you can use the classes the jdk provides? `Path`, `Files` etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this expression would also function here, even though your original expression is OK.

```
^\/src\/main\/java(\/[^\/]+)?\/\*\.java$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/37IXGh/1/)

My guess is that here we wish to pass:

```
/src/main/java/{any_package}/*.java
/src/main/java/*.java
```

If the second one is undesired, then we would simply remove the optional group:

```
^\/src\/main\/java(\/[^\/]+)\/\*\.java$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lmTOka/1)

and it might still work.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^\\/src\\/main\\/java(\\/[^\\/]+)\\/\\*\\.java$";
final String string = "/src/main/java/{any_package}/*.java\n"
     + "/src/main/java/*.java";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The regex I'm looking for is `src[\/]main\/java\/?(?:[^\/]+\/?)*.java$`

[Regex 101 test demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/293/tests)

Comment: This question and self-answer is of no use. It is just one example of gazillions of examples of how to write a regex to match a pattern. Do you really think StackOverflow should be filled with examples of every pattern people can dream up? That's not useful.

Comment: Fair point. I have written it more as a reference for myself. I'm not a regex guru and today it was not a first time I was asking the Internet for exactly this regex, without success. Next time I will look for it (it will happen sooner or later) I will know where to look for. Or maybe it is time to create private wiki?

Comment: Private wiki sounds like the right place to store homegrown code snippets for re-use. You can even make it a (semi-)public wiki, if you want to share your snippets, but StackOverflow is not for that.